# Ajax waiting till other function has finished issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have two ajax calls, one using .post() and the other using .ajax() (for testing). One is triggered as an interval check and the other send mail under a foreach loop. The problem is that the interval check only returns the results once the second ajax call has finished, not during - which is want I want to achieve. I get the results I want - just at the end of t My current code is:

```
$("#cdj-email-members").click(function() {

    $(".cdj-email-content").slideUp();    
    $(".cdj-send-email").show();

    // Disable the buttons 
    $("#save-email").hide();
    $("#cdj-email-members").hide();
    $("#cdj-test").attr('disabled','disabled');

    // Declare the variables
    var cdj_subject  = $("#cdj-email-form #subject").val();
    var cdj_content  = $("#cdj-email-form textarea").val();
    var cdj_fan_count  = $("#cdj-progressbar").prop('max');
    var cdj_email_members_nonce  = $("#cdj_email_members_nonce").val();

    // Set the interval check
    setInterval(function(){                  

            var data = {
                'action': 'cdj_update_progress_bar',
            };

            $.post(cdjAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(result);
                $("#cdj-progressbar").attr('value', result);
            });

        },500);

        // Send the Ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: cdjAjax.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'cdj_email_members',
                nonce: cdj_email_members_nonce,
                'fan_count': cdj_fan_count,
                'subject': cdj_subject,
                'content': cdj_content
            },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            // Retreive the WordPress response
            var status  = $(data).find('response_data').text();
            var message = $(data).find('supplemental message').text();

            if(status == 'success') {
                console.log(message);
                $(".send-email-success").slideDown();
                $(".send-email-success p.message").text(message);
                $(".send-email-success").delay(4000).fadeOut();

                 // Enable the buttons 
                $("#save-email").show();
                $("#cdj-email-members").show();
                $("#cdj-test").prop('disabled', false);

                // Switch back to content view
                $(".cdj-email-content").delay(2000).slideDown();    
                $(".cdj-send-email").delay(2000).hide();
            }
            else {
                console.log(message);
                $(".send-email-error").slideDown();
                $(".send-email-error p.message").text(message);
                $(".send-email-error").delay(4000).fadeOut();
            }

        }

    });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Really not clear what you expect this code to do. Please explain expectations in more detail

Comment: I need the interval to be sending back data - currently its waiting for the .ajax to get its response before sending it (like .ajax is taking president over .post)

Comment: Still not clear at all. There is no connection between your `$.post` and `$.ajax` whatseoever. The interval doesn't start sending the `$.post` until after `$.ajax` has sent request. Again, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The code is waiting until it receives a response (error or success) from .ajax() using the cdj_email_members php function. whats happening is the following. user clicks submit, interval begins, ajax php email loop begins. interval should be sending back data to update the progress bar while the email loop is continuing. Once all emails are sent i'll kill the interval (need to add this after the other)

Comment: SHORT: I'm getting nothing back from the interval until the ajax call receives its response.

Comment: sounds like a server code problem

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `setInterval(function() {..},500);` calls the function every 500ms, but the first call will only be áfter the first 500ms has passed, not immediately.

That's why `$.ajax` runs first.

What also happens is that both calls are over HTTP, and depending on your server configuration (simply said) two calls to the same URL can be lined up in a queue, so that's why `$.ajax` waits for `$.post` to finish.

To fix I would put the `setInterval` inside the `$.ajax` `success` function (making sure `$.ajax` gets called first, then running `$.post` in a 500ms interval afterwards)